# set div position dynamically depending window size browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to set the position of a div element depending of the window browser size. What I need is giving the div a negative left margin to be off screen. I can simply do `mydiv {left: -900 px;}` but that would not be dynamycally and it wouldn't work depending breakpoints. My attempt with javascript is this. I know the code is not very clean but I'm trying to make it work and then refactor a little bit.

```
 <script>

   function getPosition(element) {
     var xPosition = 0;
     var yPosition = 0;

     while(element) {
       xPosition += (element.offsetLeft - element.scrollLeft + element.clientLeft);
       yPosition += (element.offsetTop - element.scrollTop + element.clientTop);
       element = element.offsetParent;
     }
     return { x: xPosition, y: yPosition };
   };

   var addEvent = function(elem, type, eventHandle) {
     if (elem == null || typeof(elem) == 'undefined') return;
     if ( elem.addEventListener ) {
       elem.addEventListener( type, eventHandle, false );
     } else if ( elem.attachEvent ) {
         elem.attachEvent( "on" + type, eventHandle );
     } else {
         elem["on"+type]=eventHandle;
     }
   };

   function moveFiltersOffScreen() {
     var width = window.innerWidth;
     var asideFilters = document.getElementsByClassName("inner");
     console.log(width);
     var offset = width - width * 2;
     console.log(offset);
     asideFilters[0].style["left"] = " offset + 'px'";
     var position = getPosition(asideFilters[0]);
     console.log(position);
   }


  addEvent(window, "resize", moveFiltersOffScreen);

  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    var asideFilters = document.getElementsByClassName("inner");
    var listItems = document.getElementsByTagName("body");
    console.log(listItems);
    var touchControl = new Hammer(listItems[0]);
    console.log(touchControl);
    touchControl.on("panright", function(event) {
      var element = document.getElementsByClassName("inner");
      var elementResults = document.getElementsByClassName("inner-results");
      element[0].style["transform"] = "translate3d(850px, 0px, 0px)";
      element[0].style["-webkit-transform"] = "translate3d(850px, 0px, 0px)";
      element[0].style["-moz-transform"] = "translate3d(850px, 0px, 0px)";
      element[0].style["-ms-transform"] = "translate3d(850px, 0px, 0px)";
      element[0].style["-o-transform"] = "translate3d(850px, 0px, 0px)";
      element[0].style["-webkit-transition"] = "all .5s ease-out"; 
      element[0].style["-moz-transition"] = "all .5s ease-out"; 
      element[0].style["-ms-transition"] = "all .5s ease-out"; 
      element[0].style["-o-transition"] = "all .5s ease-out";
      element[0].style["transition"] = "all .5s ease-out";
      var element = document.getElementsByClassName("inner");
      var position = getPosition(element[0]);
      console.log(position);
      // elementResults[0].style["display"] = "none";           
    });
  });
```

And the html code it would be something like this

```
<div clas="row outer">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="large-3 columns">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="another-inner">
    <div class="large-9">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to offset element with pure CSS based on the windows size is to use the viewport width (vw) unit, where 1 unit represents 1 percent of the viewport (usually the window), so 100vw is always the full width of the window.

http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units

```
#offscreen{
  left: -100vw;
}
```

Comment: Great answer. It couldn't be easier. I dind't know the viewport width unit. Very interesting. Thanks a lot

Comment: One note, if you're looking for IE support (as per the link) - it's rather dodgy. I personally don't like using `vw` just yet.